# Error "ld returned 1 exit status" en Dev C++, no entiendo porque me sale eso

Tags: c++, array, funciones, dev-c++

Estoy aprendiendo a usar funciones, en este caso me pide que la la función reciba parámetros y no devuelva nada, pero me salió ese error y no se a que se debe.
La verdad me vi cantidades enormes de videos explicando como hacerlo, digamos que se "entendió" e intente aplicarlas, pero a esta altura ya no se bien como hacerlos.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std; 

void lista2( int l1[], int);

void muestra();
void muestra2();

void listas()
{

    cout<< "ingrese los numeros:"<< endl;

}

int main()
{
    const int tam=8;
    int i, l1[tam],l2[tam];
    for (i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
    listas();
    cin.get();
    scanf("%d",&l1[i]);
    lista2(l1, tam);
    }
    muestra();
    muestra2();
    cin.get();
    return 0 ;
}

void lista2 (int l1[], int tam)
{
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
        l1[i]= (l1[i]*3);
}
    void muestra ( int l1[], int tam)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
        cout<<l1[i]<< " ";
    }
    void muestra2 ( int l2[], int tam)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
        cout<<l2[i]<< " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ld` es el linker que utiliza GNU. Cuando el linker te da errores, suele ser porque has declarado funciones pero no las has definido.

En tu caso declaras:

```
void muestra();
void muestra2();
```

Pero jamas las defines.

Estas funciones:

```
void muestra ( int l1[], int tam)
{
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
    cout<<l1[i]<< " ";
}
void muestra2 ( int l2[], int tam)
{
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
    cout<<l2[i]<< " ";
}
```

No definen las que declaraste arriba, ya que tienen parametros diferentes. C++ te permite tener funciones con los mismos nombres, pero diferentes parametros. En tu caso, la solucion seria:

1. Definir las fucniones que declaraste arriba.
2. Declarar y usar las funciones que definiste.

Por las instrucciones que te dieron, supongo que vas a tomar la segunda opcion.

#### Notas

- Indentar el codigo ayudara a que lo entiendas mejor. Ese `for` es confuso
- Estas usando C++. Y ya usas `cin` en tu codigo, asi que porque usas `scanf`? Esa es una funcion insegura y anticuada. No es optima para recivir entrada del usuario.